# Configuring video driver on boot

Tags: boot, drivers, fedora

I followed a guide to installing an AMD Radeon driver for my laptop running Fedora 17 and it must have had issues along the way. Once rebooting I freeze up in the middle of the boot process as it attempts to load the new graphic card configuration.

In the past with previous versions of Fedora/Ubuntu  I know I've been able to boot into a command prompt and run the uninstall script (/usr/share/ati/...) but I can't seem to get the option now.

Is there hope for me to recover from this failed configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. During boot I needed to press F2 to get a prompt. Not sure why this wasn't working before. Most details I found online were saying use CTRL-ALT-F# (F2-F6) but that wouldn't work. Problem solved after logon:

```
#cd /usr/share/ati
#sudo ./fglrx-uninstall.sh
#reboot
```